# open a popup for each class link of page not works inputs[i] is undefined how I could solve?

Tags: javascript, html, popup

this is my code Im trying to open all links of a page using a class and

**.getAttribute('href')**  ans setimeout   but not works my code what IM doing wrong

please help me

```
function newWindow(url)  {

 var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('myclass');
 i=1

 MT=8000*i;MT1=8000*i+8000;
 win = window.open(url1, '1366002941508','height=250,width=234,left=0,top=0,resizable=no,scrollbars=no,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=no') ;

 for (var i=0; i<inputs.length; i++) {
      setTimeout(function(){

           win.close(); 
           inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('myclass'); 
           url1=  inputs[i].getAttribute('href'); 
           MT=8000*i;MT1=8000*i+8000;
           win = window.open(url1, '1366002941508','height=250,width=234,left=0,top=0,resizable=no,scrollbars=no,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=no') ;

      }, 7000*i);
 }
};
```

Comment: A couple of quick things -- `setTimeout()` does not play nice with for loops -- when your timeout executes it tries to pull the `i` relative to that time in its process.  It's better to pass the index value into the function when its called so that it has a reference to what it's looking at.  Also, I think there may be more appropriate loops for node lists than a for loop (maybe for...in / for...of / foreach? would need to do some quick research)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`test1()` will fail, because when the `setTimeout()` runs, the index (i) has reached 4 (the length of the elements queried -- which with arrays/lists starting at 0 means it's targeting nothing).

`test2()` is a more common approach -- you pass the element to another function where it is then remembered and can be queried when the timeout executes

`test3()` is using the newer ES6 stuff.  Using the `let` variable declaration seems to preserve it's state when the timeout is run.

`test4()` is an example of a recursive function that will invoke the `callTest()` function with a delay between each hit.

```js
const tests = document.getElementsByClassName('test');

function test1(){
  // will fail
  console.log( 'test 1 called ... ' );
  for( var i=0, x=tests.length; i<x; i++ ){
    setTimeout( function(){
      console.log( i );
      console.log( tests[i].getAttribute('data-test') );
    }, 3000 );
  }
}

function test2(){
  // common pattern
  console.log( 'test 2 called ... ' );
  for( var i=0, x=tests.length; i<x; i++ ){
    parseInfo( tests[i] );
  }
  function parseInfo( element ){
    setTimeout( function(){
      console.log( element.getAttribute('data-test') );
    }, 3000 )
  }
}

function test3(){
  // fun with ES6
  console.log( 'test 3 called ...' );
  for( let test of tests ){
    setTimeout( ()=>{
      console.log( test.getAttribute('data-test') );
    }, 3000 );  
  }
}

function test4(){
  // delay the call of each console by n seconds...
  console.log( 'test 4 called...' );
  delayCall( 0 );
  function callTest( element ){
    console.log( element.getAttribute('data-test') );
  }
  function delayCall( index ){
    setTimeout(()=>{
      callTest( tests[index] );
      if( index < tests.length - 1 ){
        index++;
        delayCall( index );
      }
    }, 3000 );
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="test" data-test="one"></div>
<div class="test" data-test="two"></div>
<div class="test" data-test="three"></div>
<div class="test" data-test="four"></div>

<button onclick="test1()">TEST 1</button>
<button onclick="test2()">TEST 2</button>
<button onclick="test3()">TEST 3</button>
<button onclick="test4()">TEST 4</button>
```

Comment: test1() was designed to fail ... The other two tests (buttons) should work. They're on a 3 second delay. But they'll all fire off instantly after 3 seconds because that's how fast the for loop went

Comment: @MIGHTDUY I added in another function, `test4()` that will make delay between each call.